# outputField should have its own row

Tags: visualforce

I want an outputfield to have its own row within a pageblocksection.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="SPC" columns="2">

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <apex:outputField value="{!accountObject.SPC_Executive_Summary__c}"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <apex:outputField />
            <apex:outputField />
            <apex:outputField />
            <apex:outputField />
            <apex:outputField />


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

by adding the  I kinda got what I wanted but it looks like this:
[image]

adding a pageBlockSectionItem makes the fields dissapear...
[image]

```
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="SPC" columns="2"  rendered="conditions here">

            <!-- CRMT 62903 Start -->
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputField value="{!accountObject.SPC_Executive_Summary__c}" rendered="{!(!$Setup.Bypass_SPC__c.ByPass__c) && $ObjectType.Account.Fields.SPC_Executive_Summary__c.Accessible}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


                <apex:outputField label="SPC Life Discovery" value="{!accountObject.Life_Discovery__c}" rendered="{!(!$Setup.Bypass_SPC__c.ByPass__c) && $ObjectType.Account.Fields.Life_Discovery__c.Accessible}"/>



                <apex:outputField label="SPC Financial Discovery" value="{!accountObject.Financial_Discovery__c}" rendered="{!(!$Setup.Bypass_SPC__c.ByPass__c) && $ObjectType.Account.Fields.Financial_Discovery__c.Accessible}"/>



                <apex:outputField value="{!accountObject.SPC_Client_Segmentation__c}" rendered="{!(!$Setup.Bypass_SPC__c.ByPass__c) && $ObjectType.Account.Fields.SPC_Client_Segmentation__c.Accessible}"/>



                <apex:outputField value="{!accountObject.SPC_Communication_Preference__c}" rendered="{!(!$Setup.Bypass_SPC__c.ByPass__c) && $ObjectType.Account.Fields.SPC_Communication_Preference__c.Accessible}"/>


            <!-- CRMT 62903 Stop -->

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an empty `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` element to create a "spacer" that takes up one slot in the page block section's field grid.

Is important to remember, in placing the spacer element, that the grid is populated left to right first and then top to bottom. Hence, if you want to fill a row in a two-column layout with a real field on the left and a space on the right, place the empty `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` immediately after the real output field.

You don't need to use any table elements, which I'd regard as an implementation detail.

Here's an example, using all standard fields and the `<apex:outputLabel>` component you'll need to get your items labeled correctly.

### Test230901.vfp

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Test" columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>Name</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputField value="{! Account.Name }"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>Description</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputField value="{! Account.Description }" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>Industry</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputField value="{! Account.Industry }" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>Account Source</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputField value="{! Account.AccountSource }" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel>Annual Revenue</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputField value="{! Account.AnnualRevenue }" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>   
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

### Rendering

Note the blank slot after Name.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: putting these output fields in pageblocksectionitems makes them disappear

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Can you edit your question to clarify that issue?

Comment: didn't mean to do that

Comment: No worries, but the answer to that question is no, rendering conditions on the enclosing block won't affect the items except insofar as none of them will be rendered if their enclosing component is not.

Comment: I've added an example to clarify the expected structure.

Comment: I had to add outputlables

Answer (score 2):

I think, you might use `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="SPC" columns="2">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputField value="{!accountObject.SPC_Executive_Summary__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: That could work but I want the fields below to be two to a row

Comment: Then use a pageBlockSectionItem extra. Updated my answer

Comment: Could you please show me real quick